# rails emails from heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, heroku

I am trying to send emails through my godaddy shared hosting account.

I have setup the email: hello@example.com

In rails i have the following in both:
app/config/environments/development
app/config/environments/production

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address        => 'mail.thaismilejersey.com',
    :port           => '25',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name      => ENV['EMAIL_ADDRESS'],
    :password       => ENV['EMAIL_PASSWORD'],
    :domain         => 'thaismilejersey.com',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true,
    :openssl_verify_mode => 'none'
}
```

When I run this in both development and production locally, the emails are sent and I receive them fine.

When I deploy to heroku, everything seems to work, but the emails never actually arrive in my inbox.

ps: I have tried specifying the username and password directly rather than variables but it makes no difference.

Does anyone have any experience doing this or could help me out at all?

Thanks

Comment: Any change you're trying to send emails with `deliver_later` instead of `deliver_now`?

Comment: Are you using EXACTLY the same configurations on Heroku and locally? If yes, does your SMTP server allow connections on port 25 from Heroku IP addresses?

Comment: Hi @MaximeAlay-Eddine, Yes, im using exact same config. Do you know where I would check on godaddy if the smtp server allows connections from heroku?